# AWS PDF file show in bootstrep model in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, amazon-s3

I have downloaded aws url like

```
https://xxx-xx-dev.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/std_check/6557122022151745398XtquBSY.pdf
```

When this url is put in ifrem the file is automatically downlaod instead of views in bootstrap model.
My code is Here,

View File is

```
function PDFOPEN(path) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '{{ route('background.pdf.show') }}',
        data: {
            "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
            'path':path
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.status == true) {
            
            } else {
                toastr.error(data.message);
            }
           
        }
    });
}
```

Controller File is

```
    public function BackgroundVerifyShow(Request $request)
    {
        $file = \Storage::disk('s3')->url($request->path);
        header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
        header(sprintf("Content-disposition: inline;filename=%s", basename($file)));
        @readfile($file);
    }
```

So, How can read this file in ajax succss after bootsrep model

Answer (score 0):

`readfile` function will return `true` or `false`.

```
public function BackgroundVerifyShow(Request $request)
    {
        $file = \Storage::disk('s3')->url($request->path);

        header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
        header(sprintf("Content-disposition: inline;filename=%s", basename($file)));
        header("Content-Type: " . $asset->mime);

        echo json_encode({status => readfile($file)});
    }
```